# How to view wcf service in browser

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have develope a small web application in that i am using wcf service,I have creating a methods like GetData(), When i call this method in Browser it doesn't show any data just it showing blank page please help me how can i resolve this problem.

```
 http://localhost:54421/Service1.svc/GetData
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to SOAP ASMX web services with WCF you can no longer invoke them directly in the browser. You could use the [WcfTestClient.exe utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to quickly test a method. You can invoke the method directly in the browser if you are using REST and GET verb is allowed for this method.

Comment: Used this utility in the past, very basic but enough for simple methods with primitive data types.